# Jest - testing clearTimeout in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In my button component on click I am forcefully disabling the button for 500ms to prevent multiple submissions, and after 0.5s the disabled state returns to default. Despite different approaches I get two lines of code which I cannot seem to cover in my unit test.

Please see the simplified component source below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const Button = ({disabled, onClick}) => {
    const [disableButton, forceDisabledButton] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        let timeId;
        if (disableButton) {
            timeId = setTimeout(() => {
                forceDisabledButton(false);
            }, 500);
        }
        return () => {
            if (timeId) {
                clearTimeout(timeId);
            }
        }
    }, [disableButton]);
    const onButtonClick = (e) => {
        onClick && onClick(e);
        forceDisabledButton(true);
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={onButtonClick} disabled={!disableButton ? disabled : disableButton}>Button</button>
    )
}
```

The default value of `disabled` is set to `false`.
The test case:

```
(...)
it('should become disabled after click and then return to its previous disabled state', () => {
    const mountButton = shallow(<Button/>);
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    expect(mountButton.find('button').length).toEqual(1);
    mountButton.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(mountButton.find('button').prop('disabled')).toEqual(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(mountButton.find('button').prop('disabled')).toEqual(false);
        expect(clearTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Number));
    }, 600)
})
```

The lines that are not being covered are: `forceDisabledButton(false);` and `clearTimeout(timeId);`. I tried `jest.runAllTimers()` initially, but it also didn't manage to cover these two functions. The test passes and in the app I don't have any memory leak warnings (and a visual confirmation that the button is getting disabled for 500ms), so I know that it works fine and both of these functions are being called. What modifications could I try to address these two functions in my unit test?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may use `runAllTimers`:

```
it('should become disabled after click and then return to its previous disabled state', (done) => {
    const mountButton = mount(<Button/>);
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    expect(mountButton.find('button').length).toEqual(1);
    mountButton.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(mountButton.find('button').prop('disabled')).toEqual(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(mountButton.find('button').prop('disabled')).toEqual(false);
        done(); // not sure if it's required for case with `runAllTimers`
    }, 600);
    jest.runAllTimers();
})
```

Or you may utilize `advanceTimersByTime` that may you check if delay is exactly 500:

```
it('should become disabled after click and then return to its previous disabled state', () => {
    const mountButton = mount(<Button/>);
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    // ...
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(499);
    expect(mountButton.find('button').prop('disabled')).toEqual(true);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(2);
    expect(mountButton.find('button').prop('disabled')).toEqual(false);
})
```

As for `clearTimeout` as part of *cleanout* for `useEffect` it will be called either on re-rendering or on onmounting. So if you really want to check if it's called just trigger re-rendering with `mountButton.update()`. But you can just verify if `clearTimeout` is called rather check if it has been called as part of `useEffect` hook.

in general, it's more safe to use `runOnlyPendingTimers` over `runAllTimers` since later once may cause infinite loop if we have sequentional `setTimeout` in `useEffect`(but not this case)

[UPD] `shallow()` may not work well since there are [still opened issues](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011) on integration with hooks.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, after trying both of your suggestions, the test is no longer passing (the disabled no longer updates to false).

Comment: oh, I definitely checked but maybe I used `mount()` instead of `shallow()`. There still are some issues with shallow rendering for components with hooks

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011 - according to that shallow renderer does not run `useEffect` hook at all by now